# Duda orden de arry en java

Tags: java

necesito saber en un programa de java que numero me falta para ordenar un array, por ejemplo al usuario se le pide 4 numeros, el usuario da "1","2","3","4" y lo que el programa tiene que decir es que falta el 5 para ordenar, de momento tengo esto, pido al usuario los numeros, digo si estan ordenador o no, los ordeno, y me he quedado en eso, muchas gracias por la ayuda

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] lista = new int[4];
    int i;
    int temp = 0;
    boolean ordenado = true;
    System.out.println("Introduce un numero:");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.print("Introduce el primer numero " + (i + 1) + ":" + " ");
        lista[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
        if (i + 1 < lista.length) {
            if (lista[i] > lista[i + 1]) {
                ordenado = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
if (ordenado) {
        System.out.println("La lista está ordenada");
    } else {
        System.out.println("La lista está desordenada");
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < lista.length; j++) {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < lista.length; k++) {
            if (lista[j] < lista[k]) {
                    int aux = lista[j];
                    lista[j] = lista[k];
                    lista[k] = aux;
            }
        }

        }
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(lista));

}
```

Comment: te guardas el mínimo y el máximo de los números que pides, y luego recorres el array desde el mínimo hasta el máximo comprobando que existan los números consecutivamente hablando. El que no concuerde ese es el que falta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una vez tenga tu lista ordenada, solo coges el ultimo valor de dicha lista y lo incrementas en 1 para saber cual es el siguiente numero a ordenar.

```
int valor = lista[lista.length - 1];
System.out.println("Falta el " + (++valor) + " para ordenar");
```

**Output:**

```
Introduce un numero
Introduce el primer numero 1: 1
Introduce el primer numero 2: 2
Introduce el primer numero 3: 3
Introduce el primer numero 4: 4
La lista está ordenada
[1, 2, 3, 4]
Falta el 5 para ordenar
```